# Does flutter uses Javascript Engine kind of thing like React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flutter

As we know React Native uses Javascript to create native views without DOM at runtime.

Does Flutter uses same kind of logic?

Comment: The answer is "No", about which better than I've researched into Flutter. Then beside official document, this blog will answer your question: https://hackernoon.com/whats-revolutionary-about-flutter-946915b09514

Comment: Answer is No, question is primarily opinion based. read FAQ https://flutter.io/faq/#technology

Comment: I removed the optinion-based part of the question. "Do flutter use JS like RN ?" is a valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Flutter uses Dart compiled to native binary code. There is no JavaScript involved at all.

You can run JavaScript in a WebView plugin if you want.

Flutter builds to native binary code and renders the UI using [Skia Graphics Library](https://skia.org/) which is a high performance 2D graphics library that utilizes GPUs

> Skia is an open source 2D graphics library which provides common APIs that work across a variety of hardware and software platforms. It serves as the graphics engine for Google Chrome and Chrome OS, Android, Mozilla Firefox and Firefox OS, and many other products.

Flutter uses its own widgets that are built from ground up in Dart.
Basic widgets like gesture detection, layout, text rendering, ... are composed to more powerful reusable widgets like Material Design widgets and others.
All these widgets can be reused to compose custom widgets.
The source of all these basic and complex widgets is available and can be used to allow a level of customization composition alone might not allow.

Comment: two last points applicable to React, two first is your opinion, and "it builds to native binary code" is half-truth.

Comment: I voted to close the question as opinionated ;-)
How is "it builds to native binary code" half-truth?

Comment: as you may already know Flutter runs inside Java Activity and renders in SurfaceView, so it's transferring frames from Flutter core to JVM. React Native translates it's code to native widgets - it doesn't use webView, but it's not 100% native app, because of JS bridge.

Comment: Flutter renders using Skia a 2D graphics library developed in C. Why do you claim the last 2 points apply to React, when React uses native widgets. How can you reuse native widgets or parts of native widgets are composed of in your own widgets? There might be room for interpretation, but React seems not even close to Flutter on this point.

Comment: Consider removing the `What is better in flutter compare to RN` and center the answer around how flutter render things.

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to @Günter Zöchbauer:

- Flutter has beautiful sets of Widgets
- It is easy to understand as compared to ReactNative
- ReactNative has a difficult learning curve for mobile developers
- Flutter is being used to build a new OS by Google called **Google Fuchsia**

You can also [read this article](https://hackernoon.com/why-native-app-developers-should-take-a-serious-look-at-flutter-e97361a1c073).